# Grid squares not fully filling the container space

Tags: javascript, grid

so I'm building an Etch A sketch game and at the bottom of my grid container, the grid squares that are generated don't fill the container all the way. There's a grey bar occupying that space and I can't seem to figure out why. Kindly help

here's a codepen link if it makes it easier: https://codepen.io/shogunhermit15/pen/JjLdJEL

```js
//Function that repeats the rows and columns according to user input
//Within for loop, create the divs, add class and append
//Make any grid resizable within the same space
//change color of squares

let container = document.querySelector(".container");

//build grid function
function buildGrids(x, y, parent) {
  parent.style.display = "grid";

  parent.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", x);
  parent.style.setProperty("--grid-columns", y);

  let gridStructure = new DocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "squares";
    gridStructure.appendChild(newDiv);
  }

  parent.appendChild(gridStructure);
}
buildGrids(16, 16, container);

//resets game and refreshes window
const reset = document.querySelector(".btn");
reset.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  window.location.reload();
});

//Prompts user for grid size input
function promptAnswer() {
  let input = prompt("enter the grid size you want between 6 to 64: ");
  if (input > 5 && input < 64) {
    buildGrids(input, input, document.querySelector(".container"));
  } else {
    do {
      input = prompt("Please make sure your value is between 6 and 64!");
    } while (input < 5 || input > 64);
    buildGrids(input, input, document.querySelector(".container"));
  }
}

//Change color of cells as mouse hovers
container.addEventListener("mouseover", (cell) => {
  cell.target.style.background = "black";
});

promptAnswer();
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-columns: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(50, 92, 83);
}

/* top div*/
.top-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background: rgb(50, 110, 97);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgb(28, 71, 62);
}


/* Grid container and cells */
.squares {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(121, 121, 121);
}

.container-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-columns), 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-info">
      <button class="btn">Reset Grid</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-parent">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build `16 * 16` if you are taking the input from a user. just remove

```
buildGrids( 16, 16, container );   // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

and it will work as expected.

```js
//Function that repeats the rows and columns according to user input
//Within for loop, create the divs, add class and append
//Make any grid resizable within the same space
//change color of squares

let container = document.querySelector(".container");

//build grid function
function buildGrids(x, y, parent) {
  parent.style.display = "grid";

  parent.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", x);
  parent.style.setProperty("--grid-columns", y);

  let gridStructure = new DocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "squares";
    gridStructure.appendChild(newDiv);
  }

  parent.appendChild(gridStructure);
}
// buildGrids( 16, 16, container );

//resets and refreshes window
const reset = document.querySelector(".btn");
reset.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  window.location.reload();
});

//Prompts user for grid size input
function promptAnswer() {
  let input = prompt("enter the grid size you want between 6 to 64: ");
  if (input > 5 && input < 64) {
    buildGrids(input, input, document.querySelector(".container"));
  } else {
    do {
      input = prompt("Please make sure your value is between 6 and 64!");
    } while (input < 5 || input > 64);
    buildGrids(input, input, document.querySelector(".container"));
  }
}

//Change color of cells
container.addEventListener("mouseover", (cell) => {
  cell.target.style.background = "black";
});

promptAnswer();
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-columns: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(50, 92, 83);
}


/* top div*/

.top-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background: rgb(50, 110, 97);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgb(28, 71, 62);
}


/* Grid container and cells */

.squares {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(121, 121, 121);
}

.container-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-columns), 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-info">
  <button class="btn">Reset Grid</button>
</div>
<div class="container-parent">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```